# Creating a single Firefox extension compatible with both desktop and Android

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I developed a simple Firefox extension that fully works on Firefox for desktop computers. The extension uses a few SDK elements which are incompatible with Firefox for Android, like`Panel`, making it incompatible on Android.

I created two separate versions of the extension - one for desktop computers, and another one without the incompatible SDK elements which is compatible with Android. Everything works, however when I came to submit both extensions to the Mozilla AMO they were rejected and I was asked to consolidate them into a single extension.

How can I create a Firefox extension which uses desktop-only SDK elements on desktop Firefox and does not use them on Firefox for Android?

Comment: Is there not a method to check what kind of device the user is accessing your extension from?

Comment: It's more basic than that, I cannot even upload my extension marked as compatible with Android because it contains incompatible SDK elements

Comment: Good question, im not sure how to do this. Might have to get onto irc and ask.

Comment: I've asked about this in #amo on irc.mozilla.org, with a pointer to this question.

Comment: I think it should be fine to ship with code using incompatible SDK module use as long as it's clear in the code how you're detecting the paltform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up researching the issue and decided to write a blog post about the solution: http://blog.danielmittelman.com/2014/12/developing-firefox-add-ons-with-desktop-and-android-compatibility/

Here's the gist of it: There are SDK elements like `panel` or `ui` which are explicitly incompatible with Android. Ensuring compatibility with Android requires 3 steps:

1) Using only necessary Android-incompatible SDK elements (what you don't need - don't use)

2) Identifying the platform and using conditional statements to enable or disable potentially incompatible code

3) Creating and/or running the add-on using the --force-mobile flag of `cfx`

Comment: Absolutely awesome we needed an article like this so bad! Can we get a bootstrap version of this blog? :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already have completely different versions for desktop and Android, you should be able to use the use the [[flags]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#Manifest_Flags) in your [`chrome.manifest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration) to provide a different directory for the `content`, or other type of entry, based on the application ID using the `application=app-ID` flag.  The application ID is different for Firefox for Android and Desktop Firefox.

The flags are explicitly there for you to be able to have different content based on the application (e.g. desktop/Android), the version of the application, the OS, the OS version, etc.

Example `chrome.manifest` entries would be:

```
content    myAddon         chrome/content-desktop/ application={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
content    myAddon         chrome/content-android/ application={aa3c5121-dab2-40e2-81ca-7ea25febc110}
```

In the above example the URLs referencing `chrome://myAddon/content` would come from the `chrome/content-desktop/` directory for desktop Firefox and the `chrome/content-android/` for Firefox on Android.

If you have content that is shared between applications, you could have an entry like:

```
content    myAddonShared   chrome/content-shared/
```

Because you are using the Add-on SDK, you may have a bit more trouble doing this.  I suspect that there is no way to set cfx up to provide such entries, and that you will have to make them manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was looking for a solution to merge the versions into a single package that would have full features on desktop and only compatible features on Android.

Comment: @mittelmania, We may not have communicated somewhere. What I described does permit integration of desktop full features and Android compatible features (and Thunderbird, Mobile, & SeaMonkey for that matter) into a single `.xpi` package. It allows you to package as much similar code, and as much different code, as is needed for the applications you are supporting. You just put the application dependent parts into methods contained in separate files. By "package" are meaning something other than the single `.xpi` file that is the distribution package for your add-on?